# How can I hook into all property setters of derived classes from a base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, aop

I have a .net web application that for all intents and purposes of this question is CRUD with many different domain objects.

A common theme across theses objects is the need to know which value properties have been modified as well as child domain model properties. Currently we have two different systems in place for this.

The value properties is the one I am trying to sort out with this question.

Right now the models all inherit from the PersistableModel base that has these fields and methods of note:

```
 private readonly List<string> _modifiedProperties = new List<string>();
 public virtual ModelState State { get; set; }
 public IEnumerable<string> ModifiedProperties { get { return _modifiedProperties; } }
 protected bool HasModifiedProperties { get { return 0 < _modifiedProperties.Count; } }
 public bool WasModified(string propertyName)
 {
      return _modifiedProperties.Contains(propertyName);
 }
 public void WasModified(string propertyName, bool modified)
 {
     if (modified)
     {
         if (!WasModified(propertyName)) _modifiedProperties.Add(propertyName);
     }
     else 
     {
         _modifiedProperties.Remove(propertyName);
     }
 }
```

Then within each individual model whenever a property is set we also need to call WasModified with a string of the property name and a boolean value.

Obviously this is very tedious and error prone, what I want to do is redesign this base class to automatically add entries to the dictionary when a derived class's property is set.

In my research the closest I've been able to get is to use PostSharp which is out of the question.

Comment: It's the `INotifyPropertyChagned` problem (have every property automaticly raise the `PropertyChanged` event on change), there is no good solution to this. The way WPF got around it was via Dependancy Properties. The properties you make are just wrappers to the `GetValue(` and `SetValue(` methods on `DependencyObject`

Comment: I would use a protected indexer in the base class that uses a private Dictionary to keep values. That way, it could act as the gatekeeper where derived classes do not implement their own member variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While working on a different project I came up with a solution that gets most of the way towards my original goal.

Note that this solution is reliant upon the Dev Express ViewModelBase as its base class, but it wouldn't be hard to make a new base class with the features being used for non Dev Express projects:

**Edit: I found an issue with the reset state logic, this update removes that issue.**

```
 public abstract class UpdateableModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo GetPropertyMethod;
    private static readonly MethodInfo SetPropertyMethod;

    private readonly bool _trackingEnabled;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Tuple<Expression, object>> _originalValues;
    private readonly List<string> _differingFields;

    static UpdateableModel() 
    {
        GetPropertyMethod = typeof(UpdateableModel).GetMethod("GetProperty", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        SetPropertyMethod = typeof(UpdateableModel).GetMethod("SetProperty");
    }

    protected UpdateableModel(bool isNewModel)
    {
        _originalValues = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<Expression, object>>();
        _differingFields = new List<string>();
        if (isNewModel) return;

        State = ModelState.Unmodified;
        _trackingEnabled = true;
    }

    public ModelState State
    {
        get { return GetProperty(() => State); }
        set { base.SetProperty(() => State, value); }
    }

    public new bool SetProperty<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression, T value)
    {
        var wasUpdated = base.SetProperty(expression, value);
        if (_trackingEnabled && wasUpdated)
        {
            UpdateState(expression, value);
        }
        return wasUpdated;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reset State is meant to be called when discarding changes, it will reset the State value to Unmodified and set all modified values back to their original value.
    /// </summary>
    public void ResetState()
    {
        if (!_trackingEnabled) return;
        foreach (var differingField in _differingFields)
        {
            var type = GetFuncType(_originalValues[differingField].Item1);

            var genericPropertySetter = SetPropertyMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type);
            genericPropertySetter.Invoke(this, new[]{_originalValues[differingField].Item2});
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update State is meant to be called after changes have been persisted, it will reset the State value to Unmodified and update the original values to the new values.
    /// </summary>
    public void UpdateState()
    {
        if (!_trackingEnabled) return;
        foreach (var differingField in _differingFields)
        {
            var type = GetFuncType(_originalValues[differingField].Item1);
            var genericPropertySetter = GetPropertyMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type);
            var value = genericPropertySetter.Invoke(this, new object[] { _originalValues[differingField].Item1 });

            var newValue = new Tuple<Expression, object>(_originalValues[differingField].Item1,value);
            _originalValues[differingField] = newValue;
        }

        _differingFields.Clear();
        State = ModelState.Unmodified;
    }

    private static Type GetFuncType(Expression expr)
    {
        var lambda = expr as LambdaExpression;
        if (lambda == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var member = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;
        return member != null ? member.Type : null;
    }

    private void UpdateState<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression, T value)
    {
        var propertyName = GetPropertyName(expression);
        if (!_originalValues.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        {
            _originalValues.Add(propertyName, new Tuple<Expression,object>(expression, value));
        }

        else
        {
            if (!Compare(_originalValues[propertyName].Item2, value))
            {
                _differingFields.Add(propertyName);
            }
            else if (_differingFields.Contains(propertyName))
            {
                _differingFields.Remove(propertyName);                   
            }

            State = _differingFields.Count == 0 
                ? ModelState.Unmodified 
                : ModelState.Modified;
        }
    }

    private static bool Compare<T>(T x, T y)
    {
        return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y);
    }
```

Another quick note, the IsNewModel constructor flag serves to differentiate objects create on the UI level which don't need any kind of state tracking, and objects generated from the data access level which will need the state tracking.